# Do you know of any mobile websites that allows a user to crop a photo for uploading?

Tags: mobile, gui-design, touch-screen

I'm curious to see how designers have addressed this problem on a touch-screen device given the size and technical constraints of mobile.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? There's no answerable question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has this. When you use an image for your profile you use the "pinch" gesture to crop.

I have seen others do a box that has one edge draggle (to expand the box larger) then you move the box (tap and drag the center) over the area.

I actually like the second option myself.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is more of an IxD question that I've been wanting to code up. I'll let you know when I get around to making it.